# Spot on! Oh, now it is not. The hat positioner is a little off

Tags: bug, status-norepro, winter-bash

The hat positioner seems to have a slight offset to the right:

[image: Cougar wearing the Warm Welcome hat]

I adjusted my new hat to my liking, but unfortunately it doesn't show like that on my profile. I took this picture after reopening the hat pop-up. It is the same with my other hat.

**Edit:**
Today I changed my profile picture, and I have not had any issues since.

[image: Cougar wearing Warm Welcome hat]

Unfortunately I didn't test to see if it was still offset before changing my picture, so I can't tell if that fixed it or not.

Is anyone else having issues?

Comment: Things have been a little wonky this year. I’d say this is [[meta-tag:status-bydesign]]. :-)

Comment: @Cody might be on purpose, so people will gain more rep from bug reports... :P

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard: If you want to give away rep fast, just change some licensing, change the CoC, etc. Is that what it was about?

Comment: I have tried a few times, cant repro. And since it is working for you now, marking this closed. Or ByDesign. Or whatever.

Comment: @YaakovEllis: I had a hunch that the picture could be messing things up, and I experimented now. It happens when the picture is slightly too wide, and gets squeezed horizontally. A fix probably isn't needed in that case. It is weird though, since I used the same pic last year with no issue. Thank you for looking into it

Comment: @YaakovEllis I can see [it's ***way*** off for user "hat"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUFdk.jpg), maybe [a few pixels for you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXsXg.jpg) and coincidentally an [equal displacement for user Machavity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCerO.jpg), for me and several other users that I checked it might be for them (and it is for me) **1** pixel off to the left. Would you consider reopening? --- It's not a priority to actually fix IMHO. --- PS: User "hat", there is (was?) a bug report that you need to upload a 1:1 ratio image or there are problems, I think Shadow reported it.